# Windows notification not displayed by calling .exe in vb.net with process.start

Tags: vb.net, notifications, window, process.start

I have a vb.net program, that calls an .exe with `Process.start()`
Short summary about this .exe: It downloads File from a WebServer and sends some Windows notification when download started.. This algorithm works fine, if I just start my "LiveUpdate.exe" file.

This is my call in the vb.net code:

`Process.Start(location & "LiveUpdate.exe", "-f "settings.ini")`

And this is my c# notification method

```
public void Popup(string title, string description, Icon systemIcon, ToolTipIcon icon = ToolTipIcon.Info)
        {
            var notification = new NotifyIcon()
            {
                Visible = true,
                Icon = systemIcon, //SystemIcons.Information,
                BalloonTipIcon = icon,
                BalloonTipTitle = title,
                BalloonTipText = description
            };
            Task.Run(() => OpenAndCloseNotification(notification, 2));
        }

        public void OpenAndCloseNotification(NotifyIcon notification, int secconds)
        {
            var milisecconds = secconds * 1000;
            notification.ShowBalloonTip(milisecconds);
            Thread.Sleep(milisecconds);
            notification.Dispose();
        }
```

Clould it be, that vb.net doesn't allow to popup Windows - notifications? 
I'll attach more code if you need it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's looks, you can change the background image and remove the transparencies. 
if you do not, choose a background with a plain background, so it set that color as transparent and only the shape of the central image remains.

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/V2WnhOA"><a href="//imgur.com/V2WnhOA"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```
     Private x, y As Integer
    Private fondo As Image
    Private icono As Icon
    Private WithEvents temporizador As Timer
    Private inicio As DateTime
    Private tiempo As Integer


    Private Sub FNotifi_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim destination = New Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height)
        Dim original = Image.FromFile(".\Resources\Imagenes\Fondo1_2.bmp")
        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(destination)
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
            g.DrawImage(original, New Rectangle(0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height), New Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using


        Dim bmp As Bitmap
        ' bmp = New Bitmap(".\Resources\Imagenes\Fondo1_2.bmp")
        bmp = New Bitmap(destination)
        'el color del pixel(1,1) (esquina sup. izda.) del Bitmap será renderizado
        'como transparente en el Bitmap (color RGB 255,0,0)
        'bmp.MakeTransparent(bmp.GetPixel(1, 1))
        'colocar el Bitmap como fondo del formulario
        Me.BackgroundImage = bmp
        'el color del pixel(1,1) (esquina sup. izda.) del Bitmap será renderizado
        'como transparente también en el formulario (color RGB 255,0,0)
        Me.TransparencyKey = bmp.GetPixel(1, 1)
        Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom

        Dim workingArea As Rectangle = Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me)
        x = workingArea.Right - Size.Width
        y = workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Titulo As String, mensaje As String, ByRef tempo As Timer, Optional tiempo As Integer = 10000)
        ' Esta llamada es exigida por el diseñador.
        InitializeComponent()

        inicio = Now
        temporizador = tempo
        Me.tiempo = tiempo

        LblTitulo.Text = Titulo
        LblMensaje.Text = mensaje

    End Sub

<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/BW171wJ"><a href="//imgur.com/BW171wJ"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>



<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/BW171wJ"><a href="//imgur.com/BW171wJ"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I also had many problems with windows notifications since windows10. 
I do not know what it depends but sometimes works and others don't.

you have tried to show the notification directly on a clic's event of a  button?
at least that way you'll check if it works.

Anyway what I had to do at the end was to create my own notifications, with a form that is displayed in the corner of the desk during the required time.

If you are interested in this solution, I'll show you the code

Comment: Would be very pleased, if you could insert your code